# how to redirect browser to two different site with apache virtualHost?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a valid IP, e.g. x.x.x.x, and a domain, e.g. *site.com* which point to x.x.x.x.

First, I need to redirect any request from port 80 to 443 (security issue).
Second, for every request sent to my IP, I want apache to show "Hello it's 
working" (/var/www/index.html) and everyone request to my domain to show the real site.

I tried this, but it did not work:

```xml
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:433>
    ServerName x.x.x.x
    ServerAlias x.x.x.x
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost site.com:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you cannot both respond and redirect the same request...you could return a page and then redirect it with a meta refresh after a few seconds: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for redirection:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   Redirect / https://www.yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

for domain separation:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain"
</VirtualHost>
```